# Custom control data not binding

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

Custom control for data grid view in winforms

> In my Windows forms control library:

for MyGrid.cs (where MyGrid.cs is a component class)

public MyGrid : `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView`

I have some properties set as

> this.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor =
>   System.Drawing.Color.Green;

```
this.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
```

I build and i have MyGrid.dll & i have added that in my visual studio toolbox (also referenced that dll in my consuming winform app).

Consuming winform app:

1. In Form1.cs, i drag and drop that MyGrid  & i write this code:

> ```
> MyGrid1.DataSource=ds.Table[0]; //Dataset
> ```

The grid doesn't get bound with records, whereas when i check ds `row count it has 150 records`. The grid however shows me green and white color (ie. alternating row color), but doesn't bind the data.

This is the code that consuming winform uses

```
    DataSet ds  = null;
    string connectionString = "Data Source=test;Initial Catalog=DBname;Integrated Security=True";
    string sql = " SELECT ID,FirstName from table1 ";
    SqlConnection connection = null;            


     connnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
     SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
     ds= new System.Data.DataSet();
     connection.Open();
     dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Table1");

     MyGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
     MyGrid1.DataBind();
```

where MyGrid1 is the custom control that is being dragged and dropped from toolbox.

Custom control code:

```
this.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
this.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
this.AutoGenerateColumns=true;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: when you are initializing the code or when ever you are showing the form.. prior to that do you have a Bind() somewhere .. please paste what code you have ..small snippets like that, you're expecting that we are familiar with your code / logical flow.. thanks

Comment: Did you create the columns at design time?

Comment: Added the sample code, i might be missing something, so the grid is not getting bind, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Does it work with a plain `DataGridView`?

Comment: Yes. What am trying is create a gridview as a custom control with predefined properties & use it across.

Comment: I see a different behavior, when i double click on the grid, i can see the value, but i don't see any value when the form loads, if i click on any cell value, i can see the data, so something is not allowing to display the data on the grid.

Comment: I believe DataBind is a method you wrote yourself and is interfering with the grid's operations.  Because in System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView does not have a DataBind method.  Simply setting the DataSource causes the data to bind, and your custom grid will have the same behavior unless you are interfering with it in some way.